# Proving sequence is bounded when multiplied by a constant

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Suppose $(a_n)^\infty_{n=1}$ is bounded. How do you show that if $z ∈ \mathbb R$ $(za_n)_{n=1}^∞$ is bounded? Please help and thank you!

I tried solving this question by using the formal definition of a sequence being bounded but I always reached a dead end.

I learned is a sequence is bounded if there is $M>0$ such that $|a_n|\le M$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. We also learned the theorem where is a sequence converges it is bounded.

EDIT: After receiving some comments I was able to post my attempt in the answer below.

Comment: "Show that..." Done. Now what?

Comment: If c is a constant and is multiplied to sequence {an}  you have to prove it is a bounded sequence @Did

Comment: Actually I do not "have to" but I did. Now, what am I supposed to do?

Comment: Sorry I am new to this website.... so like it is asking to prove that sequence {c*an} is bounded.

Comment: So, you are asking to prove this sequence is bounded. Now if you had had the curiosity to get minimally informed about the site before posting your homework on it, you would know this is not a do-my-homework-for-me service (well, it tries not to be that), hence you are supposed to explain what you tried to solve the question and why you are stuck at it. (FYI, the answer below is incomplete -- so you still have a chance to play this game correctly...)

Comment: I tried solving this question by using the formal defintion of a sequence being bounded but I always reached a dead end. I went through Khan academy and many other websites with no sucess. Sorry I looked at the tutorial right after I posted this question, I will make sure to not do that again and thank you for informing me.

Comment: "I tried solving this question by using the formal defintion of a sequence being bounded but I always reached a dead end" OK, but **how?** What exactly did you write? What is "the formal defin(i)tion of a sequence being bounded" that you know? Please be specific (otherwise we are just blowing in the wind).

Comment: This is not a "the formal defin(i)tion of a sequence being bounded" (and being constant or being convergent are not even among the hypotheses of the exercise so please stop beating around the bush). *What is "the formal defin(i)tion of a sequence being bounded" that you know?*

Comment: I learned is a sequence is bounded if there is M>0 such that |a n|<= M for all n∈N(natural). We also learned the theorum where is a sequence converges it is bounded.

Comment: Finally! (Forget the theorem about converging sequences, as already explained, it is offtopic.) So you know that "there exists $M$ finite such that $|a_n|\leqslant M$ for every $n$" (please keep this sentence in mind). And you want to prove... what?

Comment: How to go about proving that the sequence an multiplied by a constant, c (which is a real number), it is still bounded. Thanks for the patience and advice Did.

Comment: Once again, just write down the thing: you want to write $|ca_n|\leqslant(\text{something independent of $n$})$ and what you have at your disposal is the hypothesis that $|a_n|\leqslant M$ for every $n$. Thus...

Comment: Thank you for all the help!

Comment: Did you complete the proof? Then you might want to post it as an answer below, and even, if other users deem it correct, to accept it.

Comment: Yes, I am posting the answer right now! Thanks once again!

Comment: You may have noticed that your post received several [close votes](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/724919) and downvotes. The reason is most likely [missing context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960). When you want to add some additional information, it is better not only mention it in the comments but also include it into the question (this is why I edited your question). When other users see that you have tried at least something, they are less likely to downvote or vote to close.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773). I have retyped both your question and answer using MathJax.

Comment: Thank you Martin! I will make sure not to make the same mistake in future questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $a_n$ is a a bounded sequence. Then $a_n \leq M < \infty$ for all $n$. Then $ca_n \leq cM < \infty $. Thus $ca_n$ is bounded.

Comment: This show that $ca_n$ is bounded from above. To complete the proof, you should probably look at $a_n\ge M$, too. Or use $|a_n|\le M$ and do the both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it is possible to prove it by using the formal defintiion of a limit which is:

> The sequence $a_n$ is said to converge to a real number $L$ if for every  $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a natural number $N$ such that if $n ≥ N$,
>   $$|a_n-L| < \varepsilon.$$

$|a_n-L| < \varepsilon/|z|.$

$|z \cdot a_n- z \cdot L| < \varepsilon.$

This proves that sequence $\{z\cdot a_n\}$ converges at $z \cdot L$ proving it is bounded. (Under assumption that $a_n$ is a converging sequence.)

Comment: It seems that you are trying to prove that: "If $(a_n)$ is a convergent sequence, then $(za_n)$ is convergent sequence." Your proof of this is not entirely correct. But more importantly, even if you prove this, it is still not the proof for the original problem: "If $(a_n)$ is bounded then $(za_n)$ is bounded." (Notice that not every bounded sequence is convergent.)